# Postgres container failed to start with initdb error. popen failure: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm using `postgres:12` Docker image on AWS instance under Ubuntu 20.04.

```
  postgres-tests:
    image: "postgres:12"
    restart: always
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${POSTGRES_DATABASE}"
      POSTGRES_USER: "${POSTGRES_USER}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "8396:5432"
```

When running this container with `docker-compose up -d` it fails to start with the following error:

```
postgres-tests_1  | popen failure: Cannot allocate memory
postgres-tests_1  | initdb: error: The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the
postgres-tests_1  | same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb".
postgres-tests_1  | Check your installation.
```

The error appeared suddenly after most-resent project deploy. The important thing is that the error happens only with this particular container. There is one more `postgresql:12` container on the machine for another project, which works fine.

**HERE IS WHAT I TRIED:**

1. I've found several suggestions related to increasing the `shmall`/`shmmax` params controlling shared memory on the machine.

But these system params are already set to high value:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-246:/var/www$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
18446744073692774399
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-246:/var/www$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
18446744073692774399
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-246:/var/www$
```

2. The second suggested option was to try a newer postgres image. Tested with postgres 13.0, 14.0 with no effect.
   **UPDATE**
   Tried with `postgres:11` image and it runs OK, but I can not roll down postgres version in production, so it's not a solution in my case.
3. I tried to stop/start and reboot the instance, also cleaning up docker cache with `docker system prune` and `docker volumes prune`.

```
Software:
Ubuntu 20.04.2
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Instance hardware:
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz 
RAM:  4/8GB Used by system and other services
Swap: 4.5/20GB Used by system and other services
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maintainers of the postgres docker images have updated the underlying OS image layer:

Previous: Debian 11 (bullseye)
New: Debian 12 (bookworm)

This was pushed up to hub.docker.com on 15 Jun 2023.
The move to this container is causing a lot of builds to throw errors and exceptions like the one noted in the question:

- `initdb: error: The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the same directory as "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/initdb".`

The mitigation route is to use the following conatiner:

- `postgres:12-bullseye`

The maintainers will keep providing `bullseye` variants until the Postgres version is EOL or Debian moves to their latest `Trixie`

Issues can be found here:

1. [Postgres:12 container is not starting anymore #1103](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/1103)
2. [Postgres container failing with initdb error: `program “postgres” is needed by initdb but was not found`](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/postgres-container-failing-with-initdb-error-program-postgres-is-needed-by-initdb-but-was-not-found/48470)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was some kind of version incompatibility between Docker `5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal` and one of recent updates of the official `postgres:12` image.

Updating Docker to `5:23.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Circleci, upgrading the machine from
image: ubuntu-2004:202010-01
to
image: ubuntu-2004:2023.07.1 allowed me to use the latest bookworm postgres images.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the Bullseye based Postgres images is to provide `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` to the docker run command:

```
docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined postgres
```

This will allow you to move off the now-soon-to-EOL image, but ideally you should upgrade your Docker version and possibly host OS to support the newer Debian base images.